# Getting an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. Everything is fine except this line  Not sure why I am getting Uncaught TypeError error on this line

`this.find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', settings.color);`

especially since console.log(this) outputs the element correctly. I am a jQuery newbie, so it's probably something obvious I am not seeing.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('div[data-name*="form_background_colour"] input.wp-picker-clear').click(function() {

        $(this).setDefaultFormEditorBackground();

    });
});

jQuery.fn.extend({

    setDefaultFormEditorBackground: function (options) {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            color: ""
        }, options );

        var $colorpicker_input = this;

        var $bgcolor_div = $colorpicker_input.closest('div[data-name*="form_background_colour"]');


        $bgcolor_div.nextAll('[data-type="wysiwyg"]:lt(2)').each(function() {
            console.log(this);
            console.log($colorpicker_input);
            this.find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', settings.color);
            $colorpicker_input.closest('.wp-picker-container').find('.wp-color-result').css('background-color', settings.color);
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: can you post your console output of  `settings.color`

Comment: If the iframe source is from a different domain you will have issues

Comment: @TusharGupta it's in there

Comment: It would have helped greatly if you posted the actual error reported in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` in the `each()` callback will be the elements themselves, not their jQuery wrapper.

You need to do this:

```
jQuery(this).find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', settings.color);
```

Comment: that didn't work but your answer made figure out the right answer. thanks.
`jQuery(this).find('iframe').contents().find('body').css('background-color', settings.color);`

Comment: @renny I guess in your case `$` has been reassigned to something other than `jQuery`. I've updated my answer.